# AWS - files from were deleted by the system

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a AWS accound and I have installed ES there under /dev/elk folder ..
It was fine for a long period of time but few days ago somehow the files were deleted.

Comment: Stack overflow is geared toward very specific problem and how to resolve them, typically around coding. Even for this type of problem though, without more information it would be hard for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you have an EC2 and installed elasticsearch onto it.

What is the type of the root partition of your EC2?  Is it EBS or is it AWS Instance Store?  If it's Instance Store, then it is ephemeral and can go away at any time.

See [here](http://awsbeginner.com/amazon-ebs-vs-ephemeral-storage/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/instance-store-vs-ebs/) for a description of the differences between EBS and Instance Store.

Without more information about how you launched the ec2, how you provisioned it etc it is difficult to provide a more in-depth answer.

Comment: yes, EC2 account with ubuntu .. then on top of ubuntu I have installed elasticsearch and kibana.. I am not sure what is EBS or AWS instance store.

Comment: appologies for the delay